# Flask. Showing cookie with image at once

Tags: python, flask

Is there a way to send an image via Flask send_file and set a cookie at the same time? I tried using some 
methods, but they didn't work.

```
    if request.method == 'GET':
        cookie = request.cookies.get('some cookie')
        flag = cookie is None
        if flag:
            cookie = token_urlsafe(5)
        update(current_id, cookie)
        if flag:
            resp = make_response('hi')
            resp.set_cookie('some cookie', str(cookie), max_age=1296000)
            return resp
    return send_file('static/img/1x1.png', cache_timeout=-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the view function, you can only return one value, either `return resp` or `return send_file()`.

In your case, you can just set a cookie for `send_file`:

```
resp = make_response(send_file('static/img/1x1.png', cache_timeout=-1))
resp.set_cookie('some cookie', str(cookie), max_age=1296000)
return resp
```